# How to backup a drive contents with C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file

How can I back up drive contents to an external storage device(USB HDD) with c#?

If we can go with `sdclt.exe`, what will be the parameters?

Comment: I wonder who put minus and left. Question is clear, it can be answered with some C# code, there could be multiple approaches (high level directory structure scanning or low level drive access, which could be interesting for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how sdclt works. See [the MS article about Wbadmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015(WS.10).aspx?) where is how you can actually perform command line driven backups (that depend up sdclt)

Answer (score 0):

I found it working with wbadmin tool. Sharing the code snippet for u folks..

```
        private static void BackUpEMMC(string targetDriveLetter)
    {
        try
        {
            LogManager.All.Info("Preparing to Backup the eMMC content on external storage drive: " + targetDriveLetter.ToUpper());
            using (Process backupProcess = new Process())
            {
                ProcessStartInfo backupInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                backupInfo.FileName = @"C:\\windows\\system32\\wbadmin.exe";
                backupInfo.Arguments = string.Format("START BACKUP -backupTarget:{0}: -include:c: -vssFull -quiet", targetDriveLetter.Trim()[0]);
                backupInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                backupProcess.StartInfo = backupInfo;
                backupProcess.Start();
                while (!backupProcess.HasExited)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                    LogManager.All.Info("Started eMMC content backup on external storage drive: " + targetDriveLetter.ToUpper());
                    backupProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
                LogManager.All.Info("Backup eMMC content on external storage drive: " + targetDriveLetter.ToUpper() + " completed successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.All.Error("Test failed during Backup eMMC content process");
            LogManager.All.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```